# Android, Can i use firebase api and store database on other hosting server instead of firebase server database, if Yes than How?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am making an android application to register and authenticate user.The application includes registration and login system. I want to use firebase API. But i did not know that can i save my database on other hosting server(like Amazon) instead of firebase server, I have searched about it and I have seen everywhere the data is being stored on firebase cloud. Can anyone help me with it. And if Yes than How could we do it.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database is a hosted service. There is no other server that I know of that implements its protocols but uses the same SDKs/APIs.

Comment: If you want you can use Firebase login Api for only authentication. For data storage you can use other databases(it is not a Firebase database) so then you can host the db in anywhere you want.